# Can I check playtime on PS4 without PS Plus?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus, red-dead-redemption-2

I have been playing a log of **RDR2** recently. I have bought the PS4 only to play exclusive games. Hence, **don't have a PS Plus subscription**.

I want to know how long I played the game. *Is there a generic way to do that?* I would love to do it for games like RDR2, God Of War, etc.

If not generic, is there a specific way to check for RDR2 only?

I hope this is not a duplicate, if it is I am sorry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** There Is no official way for a user to check their playtime statistics. And as for checking RDR2 playtime exclusively Rockstar didnt include the ability to check it unlike their former games (you could check a lot of your in-game stats on their website for GTA-V etc. ). You can enable an email from playstation that will send you your **total** playtime for the year but you can't check this whenever you want.

Sources:

[1](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/76213235) [2](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/Consoles-Peripherals.topic.html/ps4_-_check_timepla-HiBt.html) [3](https://www.neogaf.com/threads/is-there-a-way-to-check-play-stats-on-ps4.1335973/)

Comment: @ShrikantRaut Hopefully playstation will implement it. I heard it was available on XBox so Playstation might implememnt it for that reason.

Comment: I hope  they implement is soon too.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can check all stats including playtime on rockstar's social club website. Just login with your platform account.

Comment: Where on the website can you find this? You can [edit] this into your answer.